# Raspberry Pi GPIO and Relay Newbie Learning Problem

Tags: pi-4, wiring

I'm a beginner with electrical circuits right now, so I apologize if this might sound a little riduclous.

Let's say if I have a switch device that's controlled by two wires. Can I use a Raspberry Pi GPIO pin to control the voltages in between those wires? Can the pin act as a barrier to stop/enable current from flowing to each wire?

---- switch wire 1
---- gpio pin
---- switch wire 2

If there isn't a solution, would it be best to just use relays?

Comment: You will need to read and learn a bit more about electricity and how circuits work before you're able to ask good questions. Perhaps consider spending a few hours doing some research and reading on the subject... not that you need any expertise, but you do need some fundamentals.

Comment: Hi @mmmm, Welcome, nice to meet you. You can jump start to connect button and LED to GPIO and day is done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UrunpqtcIE.  No need reading, just follow the pics of this free eBook: "MagPi GPIO Zero Electronics": 
https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/essentials-gpio-zero-v1
(Ch 1) Get Started with GPIO Zero, 
(Ch 2) What GPIO Zero is all about, 
(Ch 3) Blink LED, (Ch 4) Read button. But of course there is no harm reading a bit, the more you read, the less Rpi's you fry (Yes, I hate to read, and "only" fried two Rpi's in the last 2 years.). Happy frying, cheers.

Comment: You need to isolate the other device from your RPi. That's often done with an opto-isolator or a relay. You can use a GPIO pin to switch a transistor and use that to switch your external load. Invest 55 minutes of your time by watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qumu2h8FjY

Comment: Hi @mmmm, The GpioZero book's two chapters on blink LED and push button tells you the following: (1) The GPIO pin blinking a LED is sort of a current switch, switching on/off current passing the LED.  (2) The push button is NOT used to pass current through the LED, but used to send an "input signal" to another GPIO pin, to tell the Rpi whether to turn on or off the LED. I know it is newbie confusing, that is why I suggest you what Nike always suggests, ***Just Do It***. If you don't do it, you won't understand it. Better still, if you fry it, you understand better (No pain, No Gain!). Cheers.

Comment: The Rpi GPIO pin, as a current switch, can only pass little current turning on/off a a little LED. But if you want to turn on/off a 12V table lamp, or a 220VAC  lamp which requires big current, then you must use a relay which can handle big big currents. Then you need to read more: "Relay Switch Circuit - Electronics Tutorials":
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html. Happy reading. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the Pi.

Unfortunately you may well end up frying the Pi if you connect the GPIO pins as a switch (to say nothing of possibly burning your house down and / or killing folk if using mains voltage).

Can I suggest that you have a look through the [books published](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books) by the Foundation to gain a basic understanding of the Pi and especially the intro to using the GPIO [here](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/essentials-gpio-zero-v1)?

The Pi itself is happy to be used at low voltage (3.3v) and can only deliver a small amount of current through the GPIO output pins - driving relays etc can best be accomplished through a HAT or circuit with suitable protection for the pi from the switching current.