# How to cut power to gpio pins on shutdown

Tags: gpio, power, retropie, relay, shutdown

I am working on a project where i am using a pi running retropie to make a homemade arcade machine. i have wired and coded a startup/shutdown button. i would like to set up the pi n such a way i can wire a relay to the gpio pins which is closed when the pi is in power on state and open in shutdown state to turn off the amp, fans, monitor, marquee light etc. so how would i code the pi so that gpio pins only output voltage when the pi is running and not shutdown?
(i apologise if this question makes me look like a noob. i am only 13 and very new to the pi...)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Pi.  I would save risking your Pi and look to the Witty Pi range of boards - cheaper than a fried Pi.  As for learning about the GPIO, look at the guides at https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books esp https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/essentials-gpio-zero-v1 all available as PDFs or printed books.

Comment: Once the Pi loses power (**Like you shut down the Pi properly** and pulled the plug **after**), the GPIO and power pins will lose power.

Comment: The fun thing comes turning it back on as you do not have power to the gpio without powering the relay and that needs power to the gpio etc etc.  You end up with a diode and transistor to power back on in parallel to the gpio off. Gets messy :). I used to have a rack pdu that had a delay to the sockets.  You said two mins to the socket and it shut Disney then giving servers time to end - very very costly but cheaper than a two / three hour drive to reboot a rack.

Comment: Hi @Aaron. Welcome and nice to meet you. So you are 13, going on 14, and would like to DIY an arcade machine. You would like to start with GPIO and also relays. Let me see if I can find some newbie friendly tutorials for you. I need to google a bit and then come back to your later. / to continue,

Comment: You might like to read my comments to the following question and see if they are helpful: (1) "Raspberry Pi GPIO and Relay Newbie Learning Problem": https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112386/raspberry-pi-gpio-pins. I am happy to explain further. Happy gaming. Cheers.

Comment: hi everyone thanks for your help. i will look into your answers. the reason i wanted to make it so everything shut down with the pi is so that i wouldnt have to shut down the pi first and then cut the power for everything else on the ac switch.